# Carrierwave doesn't remove the deleted files from S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I have 2 Carrierwave uploaders - `ItemUploader` and `ImageUploader`, and am using fog.

I can upload files to S3 just fine, but doing a destroy doesn't remove them from S3.

This is my `destroy` action:

```
  def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

When I do `item.destroy`, it deletes the record from my db but it doesn't remove the file from S3 and it doesn't remove the folders.

This is a brand new S3 bucket, with vanilla settings. Also a brand new Carrierwave install.

FYI: I have tried adding `@item.remove_item!` and `@item.remove_image!` to the destroy action of the controller but that hasn't done the trick either.

**Edit 1**

So it seems that what happens is that it deletes 1 of the attachments.

The model has this:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
#  image       :string(255)
#  link        :string(255)
  mount_uploader :link, ItemUploader
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

So, when I delete an object in my console, it removes the object associated with `ItemUploader` and not the image related via the `ImageUploader`.

Why would it delete 1 and not the other?

Comment: had the same issue, added `before_destroy :remove_image!` to fix that (I'm using https://github.com/lebedev-yury/carrierwave-base64 too if it's relevant to someone)

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is something wrong with my console - because once I delete the object via the web UI it deletes all the related objects in S3.

But if I do it via the console, it doesn't work.

I will be opening another SO question for that particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

It deletes but take little time specially if you are referring file(image) from cdn.

Answer (score -1):

Uses aws sdk - https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-ruby

You can build a facade to manage your objects on 3, for example:

```
require 'aws-sdk'

class Facades::AmazonFacade
  attr_reader :s3

  #
  # Connection to Amazon S3
  #

  def initialize
     @s3 = AWS::S3.new(
       :access_key_id => config['access_key_id'],
       :secret_access_key => config['secret_access_key']
     )
     @bucket = @s3.buckets[self.config['bucket']]
  end

  def config
    @@config ||= YAML::load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/amazon_s3.yml" ))[Rails.env]
  end

  ####

  def policy(bucket, options = {})
   # Base 64 policy
  end

  def signature(bucket, options = {})
   # Base64 signature
  end



  #
  # Find object and get public urls
  #


  def url_link(obj, expires)
    @bucket.objects[obj].url_for(:read, :secure => true, :expires => 10*60).to_s
  end

  def object_exists_on_amazon?(obj)
    @bucket.objects[obj].exists?
  end

  def object_size(obj)
    unless Rails.env.test?
      @bucket.objects[obj].content_length
    end
  end

  def object_upload_date(obj)
    @bucket.objects[obj].last_modified
  end



  #
  # create, delete objects
  #


  def store_object_on_amazon(obj, file, access)
    @bucket.objects[obj].write(file, :acl => access)
  end

  def delete_object_on_amazon(obj)
    @bucket.objects[obj].delete(:force => true)
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't want to have to go through all of this. I believe Carrierwave SHOULD delete the objects from S3. Just not sure why it is misbehaving now.